# kbhit function in CodeBlock not work in C language

Tags: c, codeblocks

I use windows 8, and Code::Block 13.12.

I have code C language like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
   while (!kbhit())
      printf("You haven't pressed a key.\n");
   return 0;
}
```

When I press a key, It not Stop, i don't think my code wrong, have any suggest for me to fix this?

And this is my Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHDVe.png

Update: I tested on some another computer, It work! (same code)

Comment: You are going to have to wait a while to allow the console to catch up with the very large number of printf() calls you make while no key is pressed.   Clearly you can write smarter code.

Comment: You should be using `_kbhit()` instead of `kbhit()`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235390.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [kbhit()](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html)

Explanation: This function is not defined as part of the ANSI C/C++ standard. It is generally used by Borland's family of compilers. It returns a non-zero integer if a key is in the keyboard buffer. **It will not wait for a key to be pressed.**

Comment: I tested in another computer, it work!, that computer use Code::Block too, and i use same code

Comment: @PhamThanh, `conio.h` is a nonstandard header file. It can do different things on different platforms. That's the meaning of non-portable.